# UWP: AutoSuggestBox crashs in RS1 mobile devices

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, uwp

I'm coding a UWP app. The problem is that AutoSuggestBox works everywhere, but crashes on RS1(Build 14393) phones and mobile emulators and I donno what's wrong.

This is the code.

```
<AutoSuggestBox  Margin="2" x:Name="txtAutoComplete" PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" 
                TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
                QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
                SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen" Style="{StaticResource Box1}"/>
```

Note: I removed my styles and events. But no result :(

EDIT:

The error I get:
[image: Error]

NOTE: It worx just fine in PC (any build) and mobile (RS2).And not tested in Th2 mobile phones.

> Error: The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nCannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AutoSuggestBoxIconFontSize [Line: 2746 Position: 284]

Comment: What does your `e` in the `UnhandledException` say?

Comment: @AVKNaidu  Message = "The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nCannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AutoSuggestBoxIconFontSize [Line: 2746 Position: 284]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue I [blogged about](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/cannot-find-a-resource-%E2%80%A6-but-it-works-on-my-dev-machine) a few months ago.

Since you're able to develop for RS2, I assume you have the SDK for it installed as well. When creating a style, it uses the target version (probably RS2) as the default template to start from, bringing along all new properties that are not available in older releases.

If you want to be able to run on 14393, change the target version to 14393 and recreate your style.

You can also try to use the 14393 style and start from there on to customize (I haven't tried that approach myself though). You can find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml starting at line 14174.

Comment: starting with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2, we have added warnings in the XAML editor when you use types or properties that are not present in the Target Platform Min Version that your app targets. Hopefully, that will help you avoid getting into such a situation in the future.